# Enable PHPUnit with Laravel / Homestead on PhpStorm 2016.1 to

Tags: laravel, phpunit, vagrant, phpstorm, homestead

I am working on vagrant / homestead, and have a box configured.

I could enable Xdebug in PhpStorm!

Now, I want to enable PHPUnit, but I can't do it...

I followed several tutorials:
https://blog.mayflower.de/5274-Run-your-tests-with-PHPStorm-on-your-vagrant-box.html
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+PHPUnit+tests+over+SSH+on+a+remote+server+with+PhpStorm
Here are my settings:

[image: Php 7 Interpreter Via Vagrant]

[image: Php 7 Interpreter]

[image: Server]

[image: Phpunit]

[image: Configuration]

Here is the message I receive when running PhpUnit with Code Coverage

```
vagrant:///Users/julien/Homestead/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.coverage_enable=1 /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --coverage-clover   /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/coverage/Laravel_PhpUnit.coverage -- configuration /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/autoload.php  /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/tests/functional
Testing started at 11:12 AM ...


bash: line 0: cd:  /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/tests/functional: No such file or  directory
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Cannot create phar  '/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/bin', file extension (or combination) not  recognised or the directory does not exist in  /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php:181
Stack trace:
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Cannot create phar   '/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/bin', file extension (or combination) not  recognised or the directory does not exist in  /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php on line 181#0  /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php(181): Phar- >__construct('/home/vagrant/C...')

#1 /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php(250):    IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init()

#2 {main}
UnexpectedValueException: Cannot create phar '/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/bin', file extension (or combination) not recognised or the directory does not exist in /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php on line 181
thrown in /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php on line 181

Call Stack:
0.0006     442920   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php:0
0.0006     442920   2. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init() /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php:250
0.0006     451168   3. Phar->__construct() /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php:181


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting up vagrant with PhpStorm and PHPUnit can be a little bit daunting as it is really not that straight forward... From your console output I'd say that your interpreter setting is not correct since it executes PHP on your local machine.

The way that always worked for me was setting up vagrant as SFTP Deployment Configuration and use that configuration as PHP interpreter. As you are already using Homesteasd, these tutorials might shed some more light onto the setup:

- [Setting up PhpStorm with Vagrant on a Laravel Homestead box](http://www.pascallandau.com/blog/phpstorm-with-vagrant-using-laravel-homestead-on-windows-10/)
- [Setting up Laravel with PHPUnit on Vagrant in PhpStorm](http://www.pascallandau.com/blog/laravel-with-phpunit-on-vagrant-in-phpstorm/)

Here are the essential parts:

[image: Set interpreter]
[image: Configure STFP Deployment]
[image: Configure path mappings]
[image: Configure PHPUnit]